# Workflow Doesn't Work with OU

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I've created a workflow for a list in SharePoint 2013.

When I give initiating users Contribute permission using OU, the workflow goes into suspended mode.

But when I give initiating users Contribute permission one by one, without the use of OU the workflow works.

This is really confusing, because in both cases, when I `Check Permission` on the initiating user, it says the same thing: `Contribute`.

What's up?

Answer (score 1):

For 2013, if you give permissions by adding users to AD-groups, or in your case OU, it will take some time for the permissions to actually be added to the user.

This is due to the default lifetime of claims (which is default authentication in SP2013) is I think 12 hours. So if a user has already been logged in less than 12 hours ago, SharePoint will not update his/her claim and therefore will not know of the new groups /OUs the user has been added to.

[Here is a blogpost](http://www.andrewjbillings.com/sharepoint-2013-claims-authentication-ad-group-changes-not-reflected/) with more details, including a script for how to change this lifetime